# When running script: "julia -i run/run_nf.jl", the error following error is displayed "Could not determine command"

Tags: julia

When I input the command
"julia -i run/run_nf.jl" the error "could not determine command" is shown.

before the error is shown this is how my cd looks like:

[image: Current directory]

After activating the project with the command "activate." The following text is displayed in purple color "[image: display text after activation]"

Finally with the command "julia -i run/run_nf.jl"  I run the script "run_nf.jl" that is located on the folder "run". However, instead of running the script the following error is displayed.

The instruction for running and installing the necessary pachages are described in detail here:
[Instruction, which I am based to run my script](https://github.com/dynamicslab/NormalFormAE)

[image: Error display]

Comment: You are supposed to run `julia -i run/run_nf.jl` from your shell, not the package manager REPL mode.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fredrikekre mentioned in the comments, you are trying to run a terminal command from the Julia REPL's PKG mode, which will not work. You have two options:

1. Run the command from inside the REPL's shell mode by first using the "delete" or "backspace" key to exit out of the Pkg mode (you will see the prompt change) and then typing in `;` which switched the REPL to shell mode and then you can run that command.
2. Same as above in that you need to exit the Pkg mode by clicking the "delete" or "backspace" key on you computer, and then you can run (from the REPL) `include("run/run_nf.jl")` which will run the file (assuming that is the correct file path).

I will also make a PR to that package you linked above to update the docs to be more clear. Edit, link to PR: https://github.com/dynamicslab/NormalFormAE/pull/7

Comment: I just went inside the shell mode and run the command  include("run/run_nf.jl"), The following error is displayed: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Check your current dir via "pwd" or the like. You likely need to switch your active dir to the project folder on your computer.

Comment: I was able to run the script. Unfortunately another error is shown it says: 

"
shell> julia -i run/run_nf.jl
  Activating new environment at `/home/kaliam/NormalFormAE/Project.toml`
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package NormalFormAE not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("NormalFormAE")` to install the NormalFormAE package."